# Unity background and Camera

Tags: unity-game-engine, background-image

I have my camera at 0,0,-10 and my background at 0,0,0. All my game components are in first quadrant. But, in play mode, The camera shows all four quadrants. How to get it focused on first quadrant only? 
  I do not need to change camera position as I have been following tutorials and they have exactly the same scenario but their camera  renders just the first quadrant which is what I need.

I have attached the snapshot of how it looks in the game mode. This blue thing in background is all unused space since I added my game objects starting from 0, 0 to the right.

Tutorial link : [Video Tutorial(Jump to 43:30 for the game output)](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZkGPoZOQE5Q&index=4&list=PLt_Y3Hw1v3QSFdh-evJbfkxCK_bjUD37n)
[image]

Answer (score 2):

Move your camera:

1. open both game and scene windows at the same time (click "layout" in top-right corner and select "2 by 3")
2. select your camera in the hierarchy or scene editor
3. drag it until the view in your game window is OK.

To scale the view, change the values of "field of view" or "size" in the camera's inspector.

Comment: But that will need me to change the camera position, All the tutorials that i have followed(not in just 1), in all of them , they keep their objects in first quadrant and the camera at 0,0 and the game view is just fine for them. Any other change that might be needed?

Comment: Possibly the camera is moved by script or some other means. Please provide a link to one of the tutorials.